# segmentation fault, address out of bounds

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a function that takes a string of input from the user until newline is hit, then parses the string into each word and puts them into an array.

The problem I get is when you first start the program, if you enter in whitespace as input, it gets a segmentation fault. If you put in anything else, it runs fine. Then if you put just whitespace as input after that, it runs fine as well.

Here is a snippet of the function:

```
#define MAXARGS 10

char buf[100];
char cmd[MAXARGS][100];
char *bp = NULL;
int i, n;

for (i = 0; i < MAXARGS; i++)
    strcpy(cmd[i], "");

fputs(" >> ", stdout);
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
bp = buf;

for (i = 0; i < MAXARGS; i++)
{
    sscanf(bp, "%99s%n", cmd[i], &n);
    bp += n;
    while (*bp == ' ') // segfault is here
        bp += 1;
}
```

I'm on Windows running MinGW with MSYS.
When I run it through GDB I get:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0040152d in command () at main.c:46
46                              while (*bp == ' ')
(gdb) print bp
$1 = 0x47291c <Address 0x47291c out of bounds>
(gdb) print *bp
Cannot access memory at address 0x47291c
```

...but I'm not familiar with GDB so I don't know what else to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print `n`. I suspect it gets a really unexpected value (perhaps negative ? although that's unlikely).

Comment: So it does! Something in the 2 million range... so I ended up trying to compare something at a memory address that didn't exist. I initialized n to 0 and it fixed the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @hugoblack, you are relying on side effects, you should check the result of sscanf and never use `n` if the result is not valid.

Answer (score 4):

sscanf should return the number of matched items, if it can't match anything it will return 0 and `n` will be left with what it had before, and you end up using n to increment a pointer.
Check what sscanf returns before using `n` and don't use it if it returns `0`